# How to get the IsChecked property of a WinForm control?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, ischecked

Can't find the answer to a seemingly easy question. I need to iterate through the controls on a form, and if a control is a CheckBox, and is checked, certain things should be done. Something like this

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                if (c.IsChecked == true)
                    // do something
            }
        }
```

But I can't reach the IsChecked property.

The error is 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'IsChecked' and no extension method 'IsChecked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I reach this property? Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT**

Okay, to answer all - I tried casting, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close.  The property you're looking for is [Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx)

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {             
   if (c is CheckBox) {
      if (((CheckBox)c).Checked == true) 
         // do something             
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast it to checkbox.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                if ((c as CheckBox).IsChecked == true)
                    // do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: Might as well just use a safe cast and check for null.

Comment: No, your code is not the same as what Anuraj posted here.  You never perform a cast.

Comment: No, but I tried casting this way. See above Jay Riggs answer about the right way to cast.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a cast from Control to CheckBox:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                if ((c as CheckBox).IsChecked == true)
                    // do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the control:

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)c).IsChecked == true)
                // do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Control class does not define an `IsChecked` property, so you will need to cast it to the appropriate type first:

```
var checkbox = c as CheckBox;
if( checkbox != null )
{
    // 'c' is a CheckBox
    checkbox.IsChecked = ...;
}
```

Comment: you mean **checkbox** and not **c**

Comment: Only vindictive about bad answers. Control does indeed not define `IsChecked` property, but neither does CheckBox.

Comment: I assumed WPF when I saw IsChecked along with the fact that the OP's example uses a CheckBox and the IsChecked property, but you're right; it is tagged WinForms.